# Laravel Mailer: attching/displaying image in base64 not working properly in Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail

I am attempting to attach an image/show the image in the email template using base64 so that I don't have to store the file, but I am not having luck.

The image gets successfully attached with the proper file size/name in Gmail, however the image is broken and never actually shows.

The image set in the `img` tag on the email template also does not display properly.

**Rubric for both examples:**

The `data` field is the base64 string, which looks like: `data:image/gif;base64,AJHDJsdlksdAK....`

The `name` is the name of the file.

The `mime` would be like `image/gif`.

Here is what I am trying the template (the first shows a broken image, the second renders the image with the proper base64 string but everything is in plain text as opposed to being interpreted as HTML):

```
<img src="{{$message->embedData($inputs['picture']['data'], $inputs['picture']['name'])}}">
<img src="{{$inputs['picture']['data']}}">
```

Here is the Mailer class:

```
return $this->from('myemail@domain.com')
                ->attachData($picture['data'], $picture['name'], [
                    'mime' => $picture['mime']
                ])
                ->view('form.submitted')
                ->with($data);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am following everything exactly as it shows in the [Laravel Documentation for mail under Attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail).

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode data once attaching:
`->attach(base64_decode($picture['data']), 'Blah'))`

Comment: This does not work. I get an error saying `Unable to open file for reading...` since I believe the `attach` method tries to look for a file, as opposed to `attachData` which takes a string.